# For loop array in php

Tags: php

Hello Guys how can i output this array using for loop?
This code is working but it is not for loop.

```
  $a=array('Pol','Peter');
  $b=array('3.2','2.79');
  $c=array('1','1.4');
  $values = array($a,$b,$c);

  echo '<table border="1"><tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$values[0][0].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$values[1][0].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$values[2][0].'</td>>';
  echo '<tr><tr>';
  echo '<td>'.$values[0][1].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$values[1][1].'</td>';
  echo '<td>'.$values[2][1].'</td>';
  echo '</tr></table>';
```

Output:

```
 --------------------------------
 |   Pol   |  3.2     |   2.79  |
 |   Peter |  1       |   1.4   |
 --------------------------------
```

Help me how loop this output. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your effort? Read some PHP tutorial then come back again.

Comment: that's a very basic programming problem, you're first problem is to think about the logic on how you are going to loop through that to match to your expectations. show us what you've tried to do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for a `for` loop inside of a `for` loop.

The `<table>` tags should come outside of the outer loop, and the `<tr>` tags should come inside of the outer loop, but outside of the inner loop. Naturally, the `<td>` tags should come inside both.

This would look something like:

```
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($j = 0; $j < $c; $j++) {
  echo '<tr>';
  for ($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
    echo '<td>'.$values[$i][$j].'</td>';
  }
  echo '<tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: why $c in 1st for loop?

Comment: Ahh yes, I wasn't quite sure which component you were wanting there, but that will work. Glad it helped you :)